# How return variable from simple smart contract

Tags: truffle-test

Hello I'm trying to make my first and simple test for get a variable from my first contract:

Truffle version:  Truffle v4.1.14
Node: 8.12.0

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract SimpleContract {
  bytes32  hello = "hello";
  function getHello() public view returns (bytes32){
    return hello;
  }
}
```

And I did a simple test like:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";

import "../contracts/SimpleContract.sol";


contract TestSimpleContract {

  function testGetHello() public {
    SimpleContract w = SimpleContract(DeployedAddresses.SimpleContract());
    bytes32  expected = "hello";
    bytes32  hello = w.getHello();

    Assert.equal(hello,expected, "SHould hello!");
  }
}
```

And I have a Migrations:

```
var Simple = artifacts.require("SimpleContract");


module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Simple);
};
```

And I have this truffle config

```
module.exports = {
   networks: {
     development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "5777"
    }
   }
 };
```

But I can't understand and how figure out why it return this error:

> 1) TestSimpleContract
>          testGetHello:
>        Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
>         at Object.InvalidResponse (C:\Users\Lorenzo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\errors.js:38:1)
>         at C:\Users\Lorenzo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\requestmanager.js:86:1
>         at C:\Users\Lorenzo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-provider\wrapper.js:134:1
>         at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\Lorenzo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\httpprovider.js:128:1)
>         at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\Lorenzo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:64:1)
>         at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\Lorenzo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:354:1)
>         at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\Users\Lorenzo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:509:1)
>         at IncomingMessage. (C:\Users\Lorenzo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:469:1)
>         at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
>         at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
>         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)

Comment: the code looks fine for me, how do you run the test?

Comment: what version of truffle?

Comment: Truffle v4.1.14

Answer (score 0):

The issue happend with `ganache-cli`. In order to fix it you need to run `ganache-cli` with `networkId`

```
> ganache-cli -i 5777
```

Comment: yes! I've already done.
I edit my questions.

Comment: interesting catch, I can reproduce the issue with `ganache-cli`, but can't reproduce with `ganache`, test is green

Comment: @LorenzoBerti found an issue, updates answer

Comment: Thank you I'm trying to install ganache-cli and I will try!

Comment: unfortunately, I receive same error :/

Comment: could you share truffle config?

Comment: yes I update the question!

Comment: no ideas, test are green for me with `ganache-cli -i 5777 -p 7545`. make sure that you use right instances (I mean `ganache` or `ganache-cli`), update `pragma solidity ^0.4.24;`

Comment: Use some newer compiler... 0.4.24 at least.

Comment: Finnaly I found my fucking error! the file of migration, was "migration" and not "migration.js" :/ :/ :/ :/